# How to pass string literal into a filter function in javascript

Tags: javascript, string-literals

I want to pass a string literal to a filter function.

the outcome should be

```
filter = data.filter(o => o.tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(("website").toLowerCase()) != -1 &&
          o.tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(("phone").toLowerCase()) != -1
```

What I am currently doing is

- Use a for loop to get all the tags in the array
- form a string query and perform a filter in the array
- the problem is when the filter is passed, it returns everything, meaning the string literal in not working

```
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
          if (i + 1 >= values.length) {
            query = query.concat(` o.tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(("${values[i]}").toLowerCase()) != -1 `);
          } else {
            query = query.concat(` o.tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(("${values[i]}").toLowerCase()) != -1 && `);
          }

        }
let filter = data.filter(o => `${query}`);
        debugger;
```

A sample snippet of what I am trying to filter.
I want to make this filter function to be dynamic

```js
data=[{name:"fpl.xlsx",author:"hello",hits:6,date:"2020-01-01",tag:"logo,website"}
,{name:"corporate.pptx",author:"hellob",hits:1,date:"2020-02-01",tag:"logo"},
{name:"index.html",author:"hellob",hits:7,date:"2020-02-02",tag:"logo,abc"}

]

let filter=[];
filter=data.filter(o=>o.tag.indexOf("logo")!=-1 && o.tag.indexOf("abc")!=-1)

console.log(filter);
```

Comment: You shouldn't be giving it strings. You should produce a *function* that satisfies your logic, not manually try to cobble together runnable code. Can you clarify what you're actually searching for?

Comment: how can i create a function that satisfes my logic?
when user click on a dropdown list with multiple select, it should take these inputs and filter the array accordingly, how would you approach to solve this ?

Comment: The logic is check if the selected tags is in the array
e.g. website, phone
or website, phone ,abc
`filter = data.filter(o => o.tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(("website").toLowerCase()) != -1 &&
          o.tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(("phone").toLowerCase()) != -1
`
this is the logic

Comment: What is the data you have and what is sample input and output you expect? It's hard trying to reverse engineer intentions from code, so can you add description to your question?

Comment: I have a dropdown list
the dropdown list have selected website and phone.
i want to filter the array with tags of website and phone

Comment: This is the Logic and output I want
filter = data.filter(o => o.tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(("website").toLowerCase()) != -1 &&
          o.tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(("phone").toLowerCase()) != -1


how can I create this logic/ function dynamically?
I have created it using for loop but it turned out to be display it as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make sure *all* of the `values` match an item that's in `tag`, then you can use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to do it.

```js
const arr1 = ["aardvark", "ant", "alien"];
const arr2 = ["apple", "audi", "bcoccoli"];

const startsWithA = word => word[0] === "a";

console.log(arr1.every(startsWithA));
console.log(arr2.every(startsWithA));
```

Furthermore, the [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method can be used instead of `.indexOf` since it directly returns a boolean.

```js
const word = "applesauce";

console.log(word.includes("apple"));
console.log(word.includes("sauce"));
```

So we get this:

```js
const data = [{name:"fpl.xlsx",author:"hello",hits:6,date:"2020-01-01",tag:"logo,website"}
,{name:"corporate.pptx",author:"hellob",hits:1,date:"2020-02-01",tag:"logo"},
{name:"index.html",author:"hellob",hits:7,date:"2020-02-02",tag:"logo,abc"}]

const values = ["logo", "abc"];

let result = data
  .filter(
    ({tag}) => values.every(
        value => tag.toLowerCase()
            .includes(value.toLowerCase())
     ) 
  )
  
console.log(result);
```

However, since `tag` contains a comma separated list, you might get false positives:

```js
const tag1 = "foobar";
const tag2 = "foo,bar";

const values = ["foo", "bar"];

console.log(values.every(value => tag1.includes(value)));
console.log(values.every(value => tag2.includes(value)));
```

A tag might be a word composed of several others and match, whereas you only want to do a full match. You can use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to separate the tags, and you simply have to find if the two arrays overlap:

```js
const tag1 = "foobar";
const tag2 = "foo,bar";

const values = ["foo", "bar"];

const arrayOfTag1 = tag1.split(",");
const arrayOfTag2 = tag2.split(",");

console.log(values.every(value => arrayOfTag1.includes(value)));
console.log(values.every(value => arrayOfTag2.includes(value)));
```

[Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) can be used to reduce the complexity of the whole lookup in which case the filtering can look like this:

```js
const data = [{name:"fpl.xlsx",author:"hello",hits:6,date:"2020-01-01",tag:"logo,website"}
,{name:"corporate.pptx",author:"hellob",hits:1,date:"2020-02-01",tag:"logo"},
{name:"index.html",author:"hellob",hits:7,date:"2020-02-02",tag:"logo,abc"}]

const values = ["logo", "abc"];

let result = data
  .filter(
    ({tag}) => {
      const lookupTags = new Set(
        tag
          .split(",")
          .map(x => x.toLowerCase())
      );
    
      return values.every(value => lookupTags.has(value.toLowerCase())
     )
   })
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, a very visual and detailed Explanation.
Just to point out that I am working on projects with requirements to work in IE explorer. 
.includes IE no support
.every up to IE 9
.has up to IE11
To check whether the values in the selected dropdown list I will stick with the indexOf with a long-expression :)

Answer (score 1):

Why you can't put `for` into your filter callback function?

For example:

```
data = data.filter( o => {
  for ( let i = 0; i < values.length; i++ ) {
    if ( o.tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(values[i].toLowerCase()) == -1 ) {
       return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
} );
```